Angular CORS Filter error consuming java web services (jakarta.ws.rs), I'm stuck... I don't know what else to validate
Here is my web.xml configuration file...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
   version="5.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!--
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
            <param-value>3600</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    -->
    <filter>
    <filter-name>CORS Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>        
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>

This is my service...
package com.intteinolo.resources;

import com.intteinolo.businessRules.security.SecurityModule;
import com.intteinolo.database.mongoDB.MongoDBObject;
import com.intteinolo.platformConfigutation.ApplicationConfiguration;
import com.intteinolo.platformConfigutation.DatabaseConfigConnection;
import com.intteinolo.utilities.Enumerations;
import com.intteinolo.utilities.JSonAnswer;
import com.intteinolo.utilities.JSonField;
import com.intteinolo.utilities.Util;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes;
import jakarta.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import jakarta.ws.rs.OPTIONS;
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Context;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

/**
 *
 * @author intteinolo
 */
@Path("utilities")
@RequestScoped
public class UtilitiesResources {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public UtilitiesResources() {
    }

    @OPTIONS
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("aboutOf")
    public Response aboutOf() {
        JSonAnswer jsonAnswer = new JSonAnswer(Enumerations.CallStatusEnum.OK, "aboutOf");
        jsonAnswer.addCallDataItems(
                new JSonField("author", "Ing. Carlos Eduardo Rodríguez López"),
                new JSonField("organization", "Intteinolo Proximity Solutions, LLC 2023"),
                new JSonField("email", "info@intteinolo.com.mx")
        );
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.OK)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
                .entity(jsonAnswer.toJson())
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Path("loadFile")
    public Response loadFile(
//            @HeaderParam("token") String token,
            @FormDataParam("files") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("files") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
        JSonAnswer jsonAnswer = new JSonAnswer(Enumerations.CallStatusEnum.EMPTY);
        Util.getDate();
//        if (SecurityModule.isTokenValid(token)) {
            if (uploadedInputStream == null || fileDetail == null) {
                jsonAnswer = new JSonAnswer(Enumerations.CallStatusEnum.ERR, "Invalid form data.");
                return Response
                        .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                        .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
                        .entity(jsonAnswer.toJson())
                        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .build();
            }
            String uploadedFileLocation = Util.documentsPath + "/" + fileDetail.getFileName();
            if (!Util.writeToFile(uploadedFileLocation, uploadedInputStream)) {
                jsonAnswer = new JSonAnswer(Enumerations.CallStatusEnum.ERR, "Can not save file " + fileDetail.getFileName(), new JSonField("uploadedFileLocation", uploadedFileLocation));
                return Response                        
                        .status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                        .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
                        .entity(jsonAnswer.toJson())
                        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .build();
            } else {
                jsonAnswer = new JSonAnswer(Enumerations.CallStatusEnum.OK, "File " + fileDetail.getFileName() + " loaded.", new JSonField("uploadedFileLocation", uploadedFileLocation));
            }
            return Response
                    .status(Response.Status.OK)
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                    .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
                    .entity(jsonAnswer.toJson())
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .build();
//        } else {
//            jsonAnswer = new JSonAnswer(Enumerations.CallStatusEnum.WRN, "Invalid token or session has expired!");
//            return Response
//                    .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
//                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
//                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
//                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
//                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
//                    .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
//                    .entity(jsonAnswer.toJson())
//                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
//                    .build();
//        }
    }

    

}

The "about" service is working well, also all my other services (from different functions, including login as an example)
Here is the Angular Call for "about", apiURL is the URL for the webservice tools.
aboutOf(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .options<any>(this.apiURL)
            .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
    }

BUT THIS CALL IS NOT WORKING...
uploadFile(
        formData: FormData
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<string[]>> {
        console.log("UTL: ", this.apiURL + '/loadFile');
        return this.http.post<string[]>(this.apiURL + '/loadFile', formData, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'false',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
                    'Origin, Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description, Accept, X-Custom-Header, Upgrade-Insecure-Requests, File-Name',
                "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "xsrf-token",    
                // appName: environment.appName,
                // token: token,
            }),
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: 'events',
        });
    }

I'm getting the CORS error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/SmartICMWS/resources/utilities/loadFile' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I dont know how to fix it... the Angular production applications lives in a Firebase project, and the Java Webservices lives in a different URL hosted in a Payara web server.
I really need help, I had tried many posible solutions I read on Internet.
